# How to change the current working directory to a specific directory and execute a program under the specific directory?

Tags: perl

I want to copy a directory into several directories and execute a `script.pl` under each directories . But the `script.pl` didn't be execute ( It didn't print Hello ) .

The content of script.pl is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello\n";
```

`$ARGV[1]` is a directory which have a script.pl under there , and I want to copy this directory to several directories ( use the names provided by `$ARGV[0]`) .

`$ARGV[0]` is a directory which have several files in there , I will use these files as a name ..

it looks like this

```
perl this_program.pl Data X

Data                X
A B C D             script.pl
```

I want to copy X to A , B , C and D and execute the script.pl under A , B , C and D.

Here is my program:

```
#/usr/bin/perl

use Cwd;
opendir(Dir,$ARGV[0]) or die "!!!\n";
@Data = readdir(Dir);
shift(@Data);
shift(@Data);
closedir Dir;

mkdir("Copys");

for($i=0;$i<=$#Data;$i++)
{
    $working_dir = getcwd(); # Keep the path of current working directory
    print $working_dir."\n";
    `cp -r $ARGV[1] Copys/$Data[$i]`;
    `mv Copys/$Data[$i] /disk`;

    chdir("/disk/$Data[$i]"); #Change to /disk/A to execute the script.pl under A 
    $working_dir2 = getcwd();
    print $working_dir2."\n";
    `perl script.pl`;  # Execute the script.pl under A

    chdir($working_dir);
}
```

Comment: "Didn't execute" doesn't provide any useful information.  Is the script in your PATH?  Are you expecting the the called script to see the parent's current path?

Comment: @JRFerguson I think the script is under the PATH , the called script didn't necessary to see the parent's current path ..

Comment: Not necessarily related to your problem, but you should avoid calling `cp`/`mv` and instead use `File::Copy` module (or `File::Copy::Recursive` for `-r` functionality).

Comment: Also, it would greatly help you to debug issues like this if you print system erros after any IO operation, either using `autodie`, or manually like this: `chdir($dir) or die "Could not chdir to '$dir': $!";` - `$!` variable contains the text of system error.

Comment: Are `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` files (instead of directories)? If so, `cp -r $ARGV[1] Copys/$Data[$i]` is copying a directory to a non-directory, which should give an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your principal problems is that you don't capture the return value (output) of the command in backticks.  You are merely throwing away the output you want.  Do something like:

```
my $output = `perl ./script.pl`

system("perl ./script.pl")
```